# Java: EnumSet.copyOf -- is there a room for improvement?

Tags: api, javac, enumset

I need to create an [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) from a Set. I decided to use the [EnumSet#copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#copyOf-java.util.Collection-) method. However, because of a restriction on this method:

```
the specified collection must contain at least one element (in order to determine the new enum set's element type)
```

I need to ensure that the collection is not empty. The code then becomes:

`enum Color {RED, GREEN, BLUE};
Set<Color> set = ... // get it from somewhere 
if (set.isEmpty()) {
  return EnumSet.noneOf(Color.class);
else
  return EnumSet.copyOf(set);`

Perhaps there is a real limitation on javac to determine the correct type of members of the collection passed to `copyOf` method, but I can't get over the feeling that I have to resort to something like above to cater for the empty collection. Here are my questions then:

1. Exactly what is the limitation that the empty collection can't be accepted here?
2. Would a method signature like `copyOf(Collection<Enum<E>>)` have solved this problem?
3. If yes, what other problems would it have created?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of `EnumSet`, I see two reasons to require at least one element for `copyOf(Collection)`:

- The `enum` class is checked for the number of possible `enum` values. This number is used to determine which implementation is used: `RegularEnumSet` uses the bits in a single `long` to mark the contained elements (allowing up to 64 values), `JumboEnumSet` uses a `long[]` (`long` array).
- The type of the element is stored and used for a runtime type check (for example, the `add(E)` method in the subclasses calls `EnumSet.typeCheck(E)` which can throw a `ClassCastException`). This seems to be necessary due to type erasure.

> Would a method signature like `copyOf(Collection<Enum<E>>)` have solved
>   this problem?

The signature already is basically what you suggest, just with different syntax:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> copyOf(Collection<E> c)
```

Here `E` is defined as `<E extends Enum<E>>` which means `Collection<E>` is some type of `Collection<Enum<E>>`.

Answer (score 0):

In light of [EnumSet.copyOf empty collection throws IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924784/enumset-copyof-empty-collection-throws-illegalargumentexception), what would seem to be of use would be a copy constructor which accepted an element type parameter, as is necessary when creating a new EnumSet:

```
EnumSet(Class<E>elementType, Enum<?>[] universe)

public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> copyOf(Collection<E> c, Class<E> elementType);
```

While the savings are small, the gain in clarity is significant.  Contrast:

```
if ( set.isEmpty() )
  return EnumSet.noneOf(Color.class);
else
  return EnumSet.copyOf(set);

return EnumSet.copyOf(set, Color.class);
```

The *intent* is simply to copy a given set as an EnumSet.  A simple, direct, expression of that intent seems most appropriate.