# EnumSet.copyOf empty collection throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, java-8

I have below code which fails with IllegalArgumentException

```
public EnumSet<test> getData(){  // Line 1
   return EnumSet.copyOf(get(test))) // Line 2
}



private Collection<Test> get(Test[] test){  //Line 1
 test= test==null ? new Test[0] : test;     // line 2
 return Array.asList(test) //Line 3
}
```

if test is null , then **line 2 of get** function creates empty array of Test
and `EnumSet.copyOf(get(test)) throws IllegalArgumentException`

I dont understand why this exception is thrown ?

Comment: The javadoc says: *the specified collection must contain at least one element (in order to determine the new enum set's element type)*.

Comment: See documenation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722808/java-enumset-copyof-is-there-a-room-for-improvement/55925249#55925249

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `EnumSet` uses some reflection to identify the type of its elements. (The set uses the ["ordinal"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--) of the `enum` values to track whether each element is included or not.)

When you create an `EnumSet` with `copyOf(Collection)`, it checks to see if the collection is an `EnumSet`. If it is, it uses the same type as the source set. Otherwise, it attempts to call `getClass()` on the first element in the source collection. If the collection is empty, there is no first element, and nothing to query for its class. So it fails in that case ("throws `IllegalArgumentException` if `c` is not an `EnumSet` instance and contains no elements").

To create an empty `EnumSet`, you need to determine the class yourself, and use [`noneOf()`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#noneOf-java.lang.Class-)

```
Collection<Test> tests = get(test);
return tests.isEmpty() ? EnumSet.noneOf(Test.class) : EnumSet.copyOf(tests);
```

Comment: Or omit the detour of converting the array to a `Collection` before creating the `EnumSet`, i.e. just use `EnumSet<Test> result = EnumSet.noneOf(Test.class); if(test!=null) Collections.addAll(result, test); return result;`